# php string parse when contained within

Tags: php, string, parsing

String is stored in $variable. $variable looks like:

```
 plusCardName: 'Plus Card', over the hills 'fire' city 'song'.
```

Need to output what is inside ''. Output would be:

```
 Plus Card
 fire
 song
```

Comment: more detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549300/php-variable-print-and-parse

Comment: You literally asked this question now 3 times really?! 1. here 2. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30549300/3933332 3. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30552175/3933332 I already explained you that you should not do that! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552175/php-parse-and-delimit-string#comment49177660_30552175 I will answer your question this time, but don't do such things again. Next time I will close them all with the first question and I won't answer them.

Comment: I have a lot of patience and maybe even more than others do. But if you don't take the time to read my comments and still reposting the same question 4 times + then getting rude with: (quoted:) *cry me a river bitch –  Adreamcathcer Adreamcatcher 22 secs ago* (quote end) We are slowly getting to an end of my patience.

Comment: you deleted your answer, how is that helpful to anyone?

Comment: if you would have just answered the question instead of all the dramatics we would all be winning.

Comment: this all started with you not reading "etc...."

Comment: I delete my answer, because I told you that SO doesn't work by simply reposting the same question again and again. But you still posted the same question a 4th time. So I decided to delete my answer because of this.

Comment: the 4th post was before i saw your answer...look at my own answer below

Comment: I won't make a discussion here, but just for the end I will give you the notice, that with 3 out of your 4 question now deleted and downvoted you are close to run into a question ban. So I would highly recommend you to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262/3933332 before your next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
function get_delimited($str, $delimiter='"') {
    $escapedDelimiter = preg_quote($delimiter, '/');
    if (preg_match_all('/' . $escapedDelimiter . '(.*?)' . $escapedDelimiter . '/s', $str, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
}

$words = get_delimited("'Plus Card', over the hills 'fire' city 'song'","'");
```

Comment: I need to do it to a $variable that contains text like  ...'/static/gf816a20'; window.localEnvironment = {}; requireQ(["everything"], function() { angular.module('environment'....

Comment: for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549300/php-variable-print-and-parse

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

preg_match_all("/'([^']*)'/", $str, $m);
print_r($m);

?>
```

love u rizier123

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Achrome It is an answer, since he copied my answer(deleted now) and posted it.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. I figured your answer was still there.

Comment: get with the program achrome he deleted it for some reason